# Using tikz inside multirow

Tags: tikz-pgf, multirow

I'm trying to recreate the following figure in latex:

[image]

Now, I dont have a lot of a problem with one of them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %utf-8 encoding
\usepackage{amssymb} %math symbols

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,draw=black]
\tikzstyle{fluct}=[dotted]

\node[vertex] (v0) {};
\node[vertex] (v1) [right of = v0] {};
\node[vertex] (v2) [right of = v1] {};
\node[vertex] (v3) [below of = v0] {};
\node[vertex] (v4) [right of = v3] {};
\node[vertex] (v5) [right of = v4] {};

\node () [above of = v1] {Una realización};

\path[every node] 
  (v0) edge [] (v1)
  (v0) edge [] (v3)
  (v1) edge [] (v4)
  (v1) edge [fluct] (v2)
  (v2) edge [] (v5)
  (v4) edge [fluct] (v5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But not sure how to create the rest. I was thinking about copying and pasting them in a table. But multirow seems to not work giving a compilation error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %utf-8 encoding
\usepackage{amssymb} %math symbols

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}

\begin{tabular}{cc}

\multirow{4}{*} {

\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,draw=black]
\tikzstyle{fluct}=[dotted]

\node[vertex] (v0) {};
\node[vertex] (v1) [right of = v0] {};
\node[vertex] (v2) [right of = v1] {};
\node[vertex] (v3) [below of = v0] {};
\node[vertex] (v4) [right of = v3] {};
\node[vertex] (v5) [right of = v4] {};

\node () [above of = v1] {Una realización};

\path[every node] 
  (v0) edge [] (v1)
  (v0) edge [] (v3)
  (v1) edge [] (v4)
  (v1) edge [fluct] (v2)
  (v2) edge [] (v5)
  (v4) edge [fluct] (v5);
\end{tikzpicture}

}
\\
& a \\ & b \\ & c \\ & d
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Doing it all in one image makes me cringe because I have to number nodes manually again. How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much ore likely that they will!

Comment: Two comments. First, take a look at [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles), and second your code doesn't works because you used a `frame` environment inside an `article` class.

Comment: Thanks for the link, the documentation I was reading all had that syntax, I'll read the other one. That particular document started as a presentation then I changed it to an article, that's the reason of the mixup. But it does compile over here, though.

Comment: Sorry for the double post, just to clarify, I was reading a manual for version 1!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to repeat some `tikzpicture` or part of it, `pics` are a good option. Following code shows how to use them. A `pic` is declared to draw your original graph, and this pic is used inside several `tikzpictures` distributed within a `tabular` where fisrt column is a `multirow`.

As you can see, `array` pic only draws part of the graph which can be completed with `labels` or adding some more interconnection lines in each particular picture. As `pic` can have a name, you can later on use these names to draw some connections between them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,matrix, positioning}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %utf-8 encoding
\usepackage{amssymb} %math symbols

\tikzset{
    vertex/.style={circle, fill=black},
    fluct/.style=dotted,
    array/.pic = {
        \foreach \i [count=\row] in {0,1}
            \foreach \j [count=\col] in {0,1,2,3}
                \node[vertex] (\row\col) at (\col,-\row) {};
        \draw (21)|-(13)|-(24)--(14);
        \draw (22)--(12);
    }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}

\multirow{4}{*}[-1cm]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\pic (A) {array};
\path (A11) -- (A14) node[midway,above=3mm] {Una realización};
\draw[fluct] (A13)--(A14);
\end{tikzpicture}}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\pic (B) {array};
\path (B11) -- (B21) node[midway,left=3mm] {Una realización};
\draw[fluct] (B21)--(B22);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
&
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\pic (C) {array};
\path (C11) -- (C21) node[midway,left=3mm] {Una realización};
\draw[fluct] (C22)--(C23);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
&
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\pic (D) {array};
\path (D11) -- (D21) node[midway,left=3mm] {Una realización};
\draw[fluct] (D21)--(D23);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
&
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\pic (E) {array};
\path (E11) -- (E21) node[midway,left=3mm] {Una realización};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw[red,thick,->] (A12) to[out=30, in=60] (B13);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure `\multirow` is necessary: just use a `tabular` next to the picture on the left.